# Use ngFor to iterate through a "more complex" object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, angular

Basically, I have data stored in a JSON file as an object, in the format below:

```
{
    "name": {
        "source1": ____,
        "source2": ____,
        "source3": ____
    },
    "xcoord": {
        "source1": ____,
        "source2": ____,
        "source3": ____
    }
}
```

I used [this strategy](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables) (go to "Executing multiple concurrent http requests") to load the JSON data into my component via a service.

Now I need an `ngFor` statement to iterate through the "name" key, returning the name values for each source. I want to display all these name values in a `<select>`. I also want the `value` for each `<option>` to be the "source1", "source2", "source3" in the "name" key of the data object.

I'm not really sure how I should go about this, and I am somewhat unfamiliar with Typescript/Angular2. What is the best strategy to do what I want? Maybe I should make a pipe for the `ngFor` statement to read my object as an array? Or maybe I should make a new class that reformats the data and just returns an array of names?

Whichever is the better approach, I unfortunately do not know how to do either one. I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need an ngFor statement to iterate through the "name" key,
>   returning the name values for each source

To iterate over the `name` you need to access it using `jsonObject.name` which will return an object.

[**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return an array of it's properties.

[**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used to loop over the array

```
var selectOptions = '';
var _getName = jsonObject.name; // will return value of name object
Object.keys(_getName).forEach(function(item){
 selectOptions +='<option value ="'+_getName[item]+'">'+(_getName[item])+'</option>';})
$("#someSelectId").append(selectOptions)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ey7hwn/)